# How to read XML data inside a response body in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have been assigned with a task to capture the XML data inside a response body of a sampler in Jmeter. I've tried many ways to save the response data but there is no luck.is there any way to save the Response data  in xml format using Jmeter? looking for a positive reply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```
2. Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. You will be able to see response data for each sampler in `result.jtl` file.

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more information on JMeter property files and properties

---

If you need to store the response data of one single sampler only, add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of this sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
new File('myFile.xml') << prev.getResponseDataAsString()
```

Once you execute JMeter test you should see `myFile.xml` in JMeter's "bin" folder, it will contain response data. Check out [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide to learn about [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) scripting in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to save the whole response in XML format I just want to save all xml tags that present inside the Response data. let me explain you whole Scenario, in my website there is a link "View XML" if I click that link a browser is open up with xml tags are inside it. I've created a script in jmeter to click that link .A similar response is generate each time as you can see in my screenshot .Now I want to save that xml file. can you please help me how to save that xml file instead of saving the whole response.?

Comment: If you need to get some data from the XML take a look at the [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), otherwise clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve. What I can see from the screenshot is that the **whole** response is the XML file and you should already know how to save it.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri i got the solution by using Xpath extractor.